# CSS style link color in nested selector

Tags: css

In the below example link 2 comes out white and not black as expected how can I style the color of link two without wrapping it in a container tag?

```
.text a{
color:#FFF;
}


.black{
color:#000;
}

<div class="text">
<a href="#">Link 1</a>
<a href="#" class="black">Link 2</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second selector needs to be more specific than the first one to override it:

```
.text a {
color:#FFF;
}

.text a.black {
color:#000;
}

<div class="text">
<a href="#">Link 1</a>
<a href="#" class="black">Link 2</a>
</div>
```

Comment: great that's the move I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

It comes out white because the previous selector has higher [specificity](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/understanding_c). One solution in this:

```
.black{
  color:#000 !important;
}
```

This can cause complex problems if you use it too much, however. Generally the best solution is to try and avoid too many selectors. Have one selector that sets a default style for links, then only use classes to change specific links. For example:

```
a {
  color: #fff;
}
.black {
  color: #000;
}
```

Comment: It's generally better to avoid using `!important` since you should aim to craft your css to follow the cascade. But yes this is valid too :)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out white because the first selector is much more specific, namely: get a link in an element that has a class "text", whereas the last is merely get any element with the class "black".

You can solve this in two ways:

```
.text a.black {
color:#000;
}
```

OR

```
.black{
  color:#000 !important;
}
```

In which 'important' overwrites other rules that are give to elements with the class "black".

Answer (score 0):

here is working solution you just apply the style to black with id rather than class:

```
.text a{
color:#FFF;
}


#black{
color:#000;
}

<div class="text">
<a href="#">Link 1</a>
<a href="#" id="black">Link 2</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, it comes out white because your previous selector for "a" tags is more specific than your "black" class.

There are two options here:

Be more specific:

```
.text a{
color:#FFF;
}


.text a.black {
color:#000;
}

<div class="text">
<a href="#">Link 1</a>
<a href="#" class="black">Link 2</a>
</div>
```

Or, you could us the "!important" rule:

```
.text a{
color:#FFF;
}


.black{
color:#000!important;
}

<div class="text">
<a href="#">Link 1</a>
<a href="#" class="black">Link 2</a>
</div>
```

I would strongly advise the first approach, but in some situations, "!important" can be a quick fix until you figure out where the real problem lies. Don't abuse the "!important" rule because it'll mess you up for the future - trust me on that!

Hope this answers your question. Have a good day.

Michael.